# Update from Angular 8 to 9 leads to "ReferenceError: SomeAbstractModelClass is not defined" for production build

Tags: angular, angular-library, angular9

I have updated an [Angular 8 app to Angular 9](https://blog.angular.io/version-9-of-angular-now-available-project-ivy-has-arrived-23c97b63cfa3). Everything runs fine, if I start the application using `ng serve`, but if I start the app using `ng serve --prod`, I get the following error at runtime.:

> ```
> ReferenceError: SomeAbstractModelClass is not defined
>     at http://localhost:4200/main.js:1:330907
>     at Module.zUnb (http://localhost:4200/main.js:1:331001)
>     at l (http://localhost:4200/runtime.js:1:552)
>     at Object.0 (http://localhost:4200/main.js:1:96)
>     at l (http://localhost:4200/runtime.js:1:552)
>     at t (http://localhost:4200/runtime.js:1:421)
>     at Array.r [as push] (http://localhost:4200/runtime.js:1:293)
>     at http://localhost:4200/main.js:1:47
> ```

I don't know what the problem could be, because everything compiles with some warnings.

> ```
> WARNING in .../projects/apps/editor/src/test.ts is part of the TypeScript compilation but it's unused.
> Add only entry points to the 'files' or 'include' properties in your tsconfig.
> ```

I also tried to disable Ivy.:

```
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false
  }
```

Then I get the following error message.:

> ```
> ReferenceError: SomeOtherModelClass is not defined
>     at http://localhost:4200/main.js:1:364834
>     at Module.zUnb (http://localhost:4200/main.js:1:364923)
>     at l (http://localhost:4200/runtime.js:1:552)
>     at Object.0 (http://localhost:4200/main.js:1:96)
>     at l (http://localhost:4200/runtime.js:1:552)
>     at t (http://localhost:4200/runtime.js:1:421)
>     at Array.r [as push] (http://localhost:4200/runtime.js:1:293)
>     at http://localhost:4200/main.js:1:47
> ```

`SomeOtherModelClass` is a class which extends another abstract class.

What could be the cause of that issue? Please let me know, if I can provide more information.

Comment: What do you have in SomeAbstractModelClass  class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a [bug](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35380).

If `"emitDecoratorMetadata"` is set to `false` in `tsconfig.json` the appliction also runs in production mode.

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned, `"emitDecoratorMetadata": false` in the root `tsconfig.json` fixes it.

I also needed to set it to `true` for my `src/tsconfig.test.json` for the Jest, otherwise I kept getting this DI error:

```
Can't resolve all parameters for StoreService: (?, ?)
```